# Propel ORM and PHP

Tags: php, orm, propel

I am making a php application using **propel ORM**. It gives me the following message when I try to run it:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Propel\Runtime\Propel' not found in C:\MAMP\htdocs\Conference\vendor\bin\generated-conf\config.php:2 Stack trace: #0 C:\MAMP\htdocs\Conference\vendor\bin\list.php(6): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\MAMP\htdocs\Conference\vendor\bin\generated-conf\config.php on line 2.

In my `config.php` generated file I have this written:

```
'classname' => '\\Propel\\Runtime\\Connection\\ConnectionWrapper'
```

What does it all mean? Am I missing some file or what?

Comment: Could you explain in what way you added Propel ORM to your project? Did you use composer or did you manually add it somehow? If you use composer, did you include the autoloader composer generates when you run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a step in the building.
I assume you have your schema.xml file complete and you also have a propel.yaml (or with allowed extension file) properly configured. Also I assume you got Propel with Composer.
If you have all that the next steps are:

1) Open a terminal and go to your project directory, where the schema.xml and propel.yaml files are.

2) Execute the following command to get yout generated-sql (I have to do it this way on Windows):

```
c:\MAMP\htdocs\Conference\vendor\bin\propel sql:build
```

3) Get your model classes with the following command:

```
c:\MAMP\htdocs\Conference\vendor\bin\propel model:build
```

4) After generating the classes, you have to autoload them. Open your composer.json file with your text editor and add the following:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": ["generated-classes/"]
}
```

It should look like this, for example:

```
{
    "require": {
        "twig/twig": "~1.0",
        "propel/propel": "~2.0@dev"
    },

    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["generated-classes/"]
    }
}
```

5) To finish the classes autoloading, you need to execute on your console:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

6) And for the runtime connection settings run this for comunicate classes at runtime:

```
c:\MAMP\htdocs\Conference\vendor\bin\propel config:convert
```

7) Assuming you have created your database, the last thing you need to do is create the tables, this is with the following command:

```
c:\MAMP\htdocs\Conference\vendor\bin\propel sql:insert
```

And there you go! That works for me every time I build a project.